# What is the recommended approach to parse a CSV file stored in S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, amazon-s3

I am using the `aws-sdk` gem to read a CSV file stored in AWS S3.

Referencing the [AWS doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#get-instance_method). So far I have:

```
Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(ENV['AWS_BUCKET_NAME']).object(s3_key).get({ response_target: "#{Rails.root}/tmp/items.csv" })
```

In Pry, this returns:

```
output error: #<IOError: closed stream>
```

However, navigating to `tmp/`. I can see the `items.csv` file and it contains the right content. I am not certain wether the return value is an actual error.

My second concern. Is it fine to store temporary files in `"#{Rails.root}/tmp/"`?

Or should I consider another approach?

I can load the file in memory and then `CSV.parse`. Will this have implications if the CSV file is huge?

Comment: "Will this have implications if the CSV file is huge?" Of course. Scalability is extremely important, especially on shared hosts where you need to be kind and play well others. Use a line-by-line file-read, not a `read` which slurps the entire file.

Comment: @theTinMan What do you suggest for the "line-by-line-file-read"?

Comment: The [CSV class documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) has a number of variations of reading/writing CSV files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to synchronously return a file object using the aws gem.

But I can offer some advice on the other topics you mentioned.

First of all, /tmp - I've found that saving files here is a working approach. On AWS, I've used this directory to create a local LRU cache for S3-stored images. The key thing is to preemp the situation where the file has been automatically deleted. The file needs to be refetched if this happens. By the way, Heroku has a 'read-only filesystem' but still permits you to write into /tmp.

The second part is the question of synchronously returning a file object.
While it may be possible to do this using the S3 gem, I've found success fetching it over HTTP using something like `open-uri` or `mechanize`. If it's not supposed to be a publically-available asset, you can change the permissions on S3 to restrict access to your server.

Comment: How about the use of `Tempfile.new`? So for example `temp_file = Tempfile.new('items.scv'); s3.bucket(ENV['AWS_BUCKET_NAME']).object(s3_key).get({ response_target: temp_file.path })`. Stores the file in the OS' temp directory versus at the application level
`

Comment: Yeah, `Tempfile.new` is actually what I use,  I hadn't realized the OS vs application level distinction though. As for your code - the best thing to do is to test it. Does it work?

Comment: Yeap, `Tempfile` approach works. I'll keep the "fetching it over HTTP" alternative in mind